# Is carbon dioxide IR inactive?

Tags: spectroscopy, dipole, ir-spectroscopy

Wouldn't CO2 be IR inactive because of its non-polar bonds?

Comment: The best way to consider IR activity of vibrations is to study symmetry and molecular point groups. It takes perhaps a few lectures, but with practice, anyone can identify vibrations and their IR or Raman activity with nothing but a pencil and paper and the symmetry character tables.

Comment: Incidentally, $\ce{CO2}$ is not only IR active, but a [known and major](http://www.aip.org/history/climate/co2.htm) [greenhouse gas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greenhouse_gas) because of the IR absorption in the atmosphere.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> I am told that carbon dioxide is IR inactive.

You're right, **that's not true**.  Since carbon dioxide is linear it has $3n-5 = 4$ vibrations and they are pictured below.

[image]

- The symmetric stretch does not result in a change (of the initially
  zero dipole moment), so it is ir-inactive.
- The asymmetric stretch does result in a change in dipole moment so it is ir-active.
- The bend also results in a change in dipole moment so it too is ir-active.

We expected 4 vibrations and I've only listed 3. This is because the "bend" (let's start by placing the molecule along the x-axis) can occur in the y direction and the z direction.  But these two motions are the same, just deforming in different directions, the bend is said to be degenerate, accounting for the "fourth" vibration.

To sum up, carbon dioxide has 2 ir-active vibrations.

**Edit** - response to example added (question d) by OP

Question d is incorrect.  Either the author 1) inadvertently switched the column headings (IR active, IR inactive) or 2) meant to use some molecule other than carbon dioxide.

The first 3 rules you learn for interpreting IR and Raman spectra are

- The number of molecular vibrational modes equals 3n-6 (3n-5 for linear molecules), where n is the number of atoms.
- An ir active band will be observed if a vibration results in a **change** of the dipole moment. The initial dipole moment in the molecule's equilibrium geometry can be zero; all you need is a **change**.  The terms "polar" and "non-polar" can be confusing, they often mean different things to different people.  Leave "polar" out of the criteria for ir activity and stick with dipole moment, it is a much better understood term.
- the rule of **mutual exclusion**, it states that, for centrosymmetric molecules (molecules with a center of symmetry, like carbon dioxide), vibrations that are IR active are Raman inactive, and vice versa.  So for carbon dioxide there is 1 Raman band and two IR bands.

Here's a link to a recent SE Chem question: [How can I deduce the linearity of XeF2 from the IR spectrum?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/18605/how-can-i-deduce-the-linearity-of-xef2-from-the-ir-spectrum/18608#18608) where these rules were used to determine the structure of a molecule.

Comment: @Dissenter to be IR active, a vibration must change the dipole moment. A polar bond can give IR active vibrations, but as the CO2 example shows, polar bonds can also give symmetric, IR inactive vibrations too.

Comment: And nonpolar bonds can have vibrations that change the dipole moment (for example $\ce{C=C}$ and $\ce{C#C}$). If you need proof that $\ce{CO2}$ is IR active, breath into an IR spectrometer while it is running.

Comment: It's just plain wrong.  Look [here](http://chemistry.illinoisstate.edu/standard/che362/handouts/362molvibs.pdf), they analyze carbon dioxide and get the same result as posted here.  They also analyze acetylene, a non-polar molecule, and again predict and observe ir-active vibrations.

Answer (score 4):

Not true at all.  The $\ce{C=O}$ bond is one of the most strongly IR active bonds there is (and the IR activity of $\ce{CO2}$ is the reason it's a greenhouse gas).
I suspect the person who told you this was thinking that because $\ce{CO2}$ doesn't have a static dipole, it can't be IR active.  However, IR activity is the result of dynamic dipoles (meaning the dipole changes with some type of deformation motion; in the case of $\ce{CO2}$, this occurs with bending motion and asymmetric stretching, as another answerer described), not static dipoles.

In some symmetric molecules, like $\ce{N2}$ or $\ce{O2}$, the only vibrational modes that can exist are stretching of the only bond, which because it's symmetric, doesn't lead to a dipole change.  Thus, those species are not IR active.