# Which vibrational modes of CO2 and CSO do not lead to IR absorption bands?

Tags: organic-chemistry, spectroscopy

I recently came across this question, I have no idea about IR:

> Which of the following vibrational modes show no IR absorption bands?
>
> A) Symmetric CO2 stretch
>
> B) Antisymmetric CO2 stretch
>
> C) Symmetric S=C=O stretch
>
> D) Antisymmetric S=C=O stretch

Comment: related question: http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/19119/is-carbon-dioxide-ir-inactive?rq=1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A) Symmetric $\ce{CO2}$ stretch.

A particular vibrational mode is considered IR active, if there is a change of *transition dipole moment*. $\ce{CO2}$ is linear, and the symmetric stretching mode means both oxygens move in/outward concurrently.
You can see an illustration of the symmetric and antisymmetric stretching modes of $\ce{CO2}$ here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TMLnUmbLwUI&t=1m50s

- For the symmetric mode, the overall center of charge stays the same, thus no change in dipole moment, thus the mode is not IR active.
- For the antisymmetric mode, the center of charge shifts, thus the dipole moment changes and the mode is IR active. This is also true of the $\ce{S=C=O}$ antisymmetric stretch.
- The $\ce{S=C=O}$ symmetric stretching mode is also IR active, since $\ce{S}$ and $\ce{O}$ are two different atoms, with different partial charges. As they vibrate, the total center of charge moves.