# Why the count of the IR band of H2O and CO2 is different?

Tags: ir-spectroscopy

Why $\ce{H2O}$ shows three and $\ce{CO2}$ shows two fundamental bands in IR while they both are triatomic molecules?

Comment: Maybe something to do with symmetry and degenerate modes?

Comment: Welcome to the site. Note, *chemical* information may be advantageously formatted using on ChemSE with [mhchem](https://mhchem.github.io/MathJax-mhchem/). Take moment to familiarize with this. You are encouraged to use it in the body of questions, answers, and comments. Because it is something special not all web browsers understand well, *do not* use it in the title of questions or answers.

Comment: Related, see "[Is carbon dioxide IR inactive?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/19119/is-carbon-dioxide-ir-inactive/19121#19121)"

Answer (score 6):

Molecules vibrate.  Some of the vibrations alter the polarizability of the electron cloud of a chemical bond, which renders them suitable for a characterization by RAMAN spectroscopy.  Some of the vibrations alter the dipole moment of the molecule; these are the vibrations characterized by infrared spectroscopy.  Both techniques are complementary to each other, and especially in larger molecules, there are vibrations which may be observed by either one.

For $\ce{CO2}$, a linear molecule, there is one vibration which does not alter the net dipole moment.  Two others coalesce upon observation since they match in energy. Chemistry LibreTexts contains an animation of all of them:

[image]

For water, already bent in the ground state, the vibrations IR spectroscopy may characterize are these:

[image]

Both animations are a verbatim copy from the entry on [Chemistry LibreTexts](https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry_Textbook_Maps/Supplemental_Modules_(Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry)/Spectroscopy/Vibrational_Spectroscopy/Infrared_Spectroscopy/Infrared_Spectroscopy) about this topic.